# Multisite Wordpress plugin feed db prefix issues

Tags: php, database, wordpress

I am working on a special calendar plugin for our site and I am running into some issues trying to collect database information. The calendar system we are using requires a json feed from the database.

For example we will have a link like the following
    http://example.com/wp-content/ThemeName/calendar/calFeed.php

We have created the database connection using the following:

```
require_once('../../../../../wp-config.php');
mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
```

The Issue is that because the system is using a multisite installation the prefix is appended with a number for each site. I am trying to figure out how to get that number my current code is as follows:

```
$prefix = $wpdb->prefix;
```

Any help on this matter is greatly appreciated.